# Hook run before first test in any class in JUnit is executed

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

My project has dozen of JUnit 4 test classes with test cases.

Before any of them are run, I want to execute code (in my case to fix the logging in certain scenarios). How can I achieve that?

My test classes are too many to be reasonably enumerated in a test suite and @BeforeClass is not helpful here either.

Comment: You can try to use suite test: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm

Comment: Maybe you better put a "test logger configuration" in place before the start of the test run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to exist an easy solution, so I ended up with a regular Spring bean initializied in the test Spring context to do the magic.

Answer (score 0):

you can :

1) configure logging for junit tests

2) add junit listener for configure stuff

3) create base test class (in you can) and do configuration inside base test class

better use special logger configuration for test

Comment: A base test class is an idea, but I have too many test classes to facilitate that.